# What exactly makes this Python question "Too Localized"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This question has been closed as too localized.

[String equality failure in Python. What gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604424/string-equality-failure-in-python-what-gives/9604487)

The real problem was an issue with an invisible character not removed by the `strip` string method. The question was asked by a newcomer, and while it did not contain all the necessary information, it was far from a bad question. The OP took the effort of updating the question with more details.

What is the problem in this SO question which makes it too localized?

Comment: The comments on the question and answer seem to have gotten out of hand.

Comment: Related: [Joel Spolsky's opinion on "too localized"](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/547)

Comment: Why was this question marked as off topic?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the close reason:

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
>   **extraordinarily narrow situation** that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet.

In other words, it is a troubleshooting question, the problem being so specific that it is unlikely to be of help to anyone else.

Note that the OP got a solution to his problem anyway.  Mission accomplished.

Comment: I understand the meaning of `too localized`. I simply don't agree. The behavior of `strip` is counter intuitive in this case, and sanitizing input strings is not by any mean an `extraordinarily narrow situation`

Comment: The question got three close votes from community members, and one moderator flag with the following text: *"Please guess what's wrong with my code."*

Comment: I am not discussing the moderation mecanism. I question the motivation in this specific case. I am not saying that I am right either. If you think the decision was correct I honestly want to know why. I understand that this is not a dictatorial decision, and that several people are involved. But the question was also upvoted, so I think that I am not the only one to disagree.

Comment: It is a troubleshooting question, the problem being so specific that it is unlikely to be of help to anyone else.  Granted, this is a judgement call.

Comment: @Robert - Seriously? Is that the flag that came over?  Somehow I get the feeling stuff like that is not uncommon

Comment: `Note that the OP got a solution to his problem anyway. Mission accomplished.` I don't think so. Unfair decisions are likely to degrade the community.

Comment: @AdamRackis It happens with impressive regularity.