# European Cookies Law Questions: Too Localised?

Tags: discussion, cookies

What's the general thought around questions relating to the [European cookies law](http://www.cookielaw.org/) and how to implement it e.g. [Cookies Consent Law](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762010/cookie-consent-laws). Setting aside issues of 'Is `insert piece of code` a legal way to implement the law', which are clearly off-topic, I'm putting close votes against them as 'too localised' since SO is a global site and I don't see any future value in keeping the questions around.

Comment: FWIW: this is one reason why we're discussing [a change to the wording of Too Localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132319/consider-changing-the-wording-of-the-too-localized-close-reason/133574#133574) - every question tends to be localized in some fashion, the emphasis should really be on *Too*.

Comment: I think I guessed wrong about a recent "too localized" vote I saw someone cast. I assumed it was because of time. (Since laws are constantly subject to change)

Comment: Think of "Too Localized" as the short-form of "Too Localized to be useful to the 'Not You' demographic." Such a question as yours would clearly be useful to plenty of people. It doesn't need to be useful to *everyone* equally, but just for other people.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See Joel's answer on [What questions should be closed with reason "too localized"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized/87415#87415).

> "Too localized" should be used for very tiny geographic regions or vanishingly small periods of time. It is used when a question cannot possibly be answered because nobody participating in the site is likely to know the answer, and even if it were answered, nobody else would care.

Something applicable to all of the EU really isn't "Too Localized" any more than something is "Too Localized" because it is in English (after all some people don't speak English!). The EU Cookie regulation is very important and certainly not too localized, however "Is X legal" is often Off Topic on most Stack Exchange sites.

As to what our "official" stance is on these questions is I can't say, but "Too Localized" certainly isn't it.

Comment: Nitpick: The EU Cookie "Law" is not applicable to all of Europe (EU is a subset of Europe) and it isn't a law either. It's an EU regulation that EU member states will adopt in their own time and _possibly_ in their own form, depending on conflicts / relations with current national laws. Still not too localized though, at least not in the geographical sense.

Comment: The official stance should be that if the questions can have definitive informational reusable answers within the scope of SO, they're welcome there. As normal. :-)